# Highstock chart not loading with sample data

Tags: highcharts

building on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644258/dual-axis-in-highstock), I am trying to see if I can be the source of the high stock data coming from the [answer](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?). Yet when I have my website return the exact same content, it doesn't work. I've tried changing it to javascript and json content types, but it doesn't seem to affect it at all.

Any ideas on what outside of the data's content and content type I could be missing?

Comment: Any source code, live demo, please?

Comment: i was just copying pasting the code from the jsFiddle in the example, but changing where the source was coming from (a file on my server). But I found the answer and will be posting it

Answer (score 0):

after noticing that my getJson callback wasn't firing, i did what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716468/getjson-callback-not-firing) suggested and broke apart the getjson function call. For some reason the json is formatted differently than what it looks like it's doing in code, it came back in this form, which makes more sense now.

[[1147651200000, 67.79], [1147737600000, 64.98], [1147824000000, 65.26], [1147910400000, 63.18]]